# Django Form in VueJS component template

Tags: django, vue.js, vue-apollo, graphene-django

I'm currently starting a project in which I'm using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) for the backend, graphql ([Graphene](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/)) for the API, [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/) for the frontend, and [Vue Apollo](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/#sponsors) to ease running graphql queries through VueJS.

The thing is :
I'm already able to do custom forms in Vue components and run the appropriate query to fetch/add/delete data.
But I haven't been able to integrate Django Forms into a Vue component so far, I have no idea how to do it.
I could be satisfied with custom forms, but I wan't to be able to use Django Forms since all the validation of forms is easy to do with Django.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

lbris.

Answer (score 2):

I find a very clean solution to this problem to use [djagno widget tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks)

With that you can have something like:

### views.py

```
def myview(request):
    form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'form': form})
```

### mytemplate.html

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<form v-on:submit-prevent="myaction()">
    {% render_field form.field v-model="myattr" %}
</form>
```

And it will work flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

This is fragment of code from [this](https://medium.com/quick-code/crud-app-using-vue-js-and-django-516edf4e4217) article, I recommend you to read it.

- you have to attach view instance to some element like **starting** (in example)
- set **delimiters**, because  we do not need conflicts with django template {{ }} syntax
- inside div with id=**starting** you can place your vue custom forms

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
new Vue({
   el: "#starting",
   delimiters: ['${', '}'],
   data: {
      articles: [],
      loading: false,
      newArticle: {...}
      ...
   }
 },
mounted: function() {
},
methods: {
 addArticle: function() {
  this.loading = true;
  this.$http.post("/api/article/",this.newArticle)
   .then((response) => {
     console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    this.loading = false;
    console.log(err);
  }) 
 },
 ...
}
 });
</script>
```

```html
  <div id="starting">
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="addArticle()">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="article_heading">Article Heading</label>
                <input
                     type="text"
                     class="form-control"
                     id="article_heading"
                     placeholder="Enter Article Heading"
                     v-model="newArticle.article_heading"
                     required="required" >
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="article_body">Article Body</label>
                      <textarea
                        class="form-control"
                        id="article_body"
                        placeholder="Enter Article Body"
                        v-model="newArticle.article_body"
                        required="required"
                        rows="3"></textarea>
                  </div>
             </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
       </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is what I already do (custom form with VueJS). What I want to achieve is to use builtin Django Forms (forms.ModelForm) that you can create like this :
from django import forms
from ..models.group import Group


class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['name', 'is_local']   (sorry for the indentation in comment). I don't know if it is a good idea either anyway.